# Which sentence is right: "What length is the river " vs "What is the length of the river"

Tags: grammar, meaning, questions

**Which sentence is right?**: "What is the length of the river" and "What length is the river"

Comment: I find the first more idiomatic, but the second isn't _wrong_. Of course you can also say "How long is the river?"

Answer (score 1):

I find the first more idiomatic, but the second isn't wrong. Of course you can also say "How long is the river?" –
Kate Bunting